# Как вставить картинку и текст на 1 форму в делфи?

Tags: delphi

На форму надо вставить текст с картинками. При этом у меня ещё не работает компонент TWebBrowser. Как ещё можно вставить текст с картинками?

Answer (score 0):

Задача не ясна, как всё должно выглядеть. Я бы например как вариант предложил использовать Canvas. И рисовать всё как душа пожелает.

```
var
 bmp:tbitmap;
begin
Canvas.TextOut(x,y,'');//выводим текст
bmp:=tbitmap.Create;
bmp.LoadFromFile(имя файла);
Canvas.Draw(x,y,bmp);//выводим картинку
```